# Android ProgressDialog query processing

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am new to the `android.os.AsyncTask` approach on handling `android.app.ProgressDialog`. I have this problem of processing a particular query via `android.database.Cursor` and convert in into an entity I would need.

I am following this template but it always return me an `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException`.

```
List<Entity> loadData() throws Exception {
    AsyncTask<Cursor, Void, List<Entity>> process = new AsyncTask<Cursor, Void, List<Entity>>() {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait...", "Loading data...");         
        }
        protected void onPostExcecute() {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        @Override
        protected List<Entity> doInBackground(Cursor... params) {
            List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
            // process of convertion of data from android.database.Cursor to <pacakge>.Entity
            return entities;
        }
    }.execute(/* the query : android.database.Cursor */)
    return process.get();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to show `ProgressDialog` from `onPreExecute()` method of AsyncTask use Current Activity Context in which AsyncTask is running instead of `getApplicationContext()` as :

```
 dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Your_Current_Activity.this, 
                    "Please wait...",
                    "Loading data...");
```

if `AsyncTask` is running in separate class from `Activity` then you will need to pass current activity context in  AsyncTask using AsyncTask's class constructor

Comment: The ProgressDialog doens't show up or rather it shows up at the end of the process.

Comment: @Dr.Java : but this is not an error because you are using get method of AsyncTask which will freeze UI until doInBackground is execution is not done .

Comment: @Dr.Java : you will need to use Thread to call  `process.get()` method or update UI inside onPostExcecute

Comment: Uhhmmm... Can you post some SSCCE to support it? I can't visualize it, sorry.

Comment: @Dr.Java : ok can i known purpose of loadData() method ?

Comment: The return object of the loadData method is the objects used in the ListView adapter. I was planning to do the loadData with the progressdialog before loading it to the adapter to avoid UI freeze caused by the conversion said above (that is without the Async part).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23980/discussion-between--k-and-dr-java)